# Non WooCommerce Sidebar Widget Appearing on Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed WooCommerce in WordPress and it will act as a sub section for my website. I have a non-WooCommerce related Sidebar widget that appears on the homepage of my website and after installing WooCommerce, that same widget is appearing on the `single-product.php` page.

All documentation that describes removing the sidebar from this page, are referring to WooCommerces' own sidebar widget, which is not the case here. What do I have to do to prevent my homepage sidebar widget from displaying on my WooCommerce Products page?

Comment: Can you give your site url ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is both sidebar files may have the same file name sidebar.php like.
Woocommerce is using the 'sidebar.php'.  So please rename the homepage sidebar 
widget file to 'sidebar-home.php' and  call it as get_sidebar('home'); in the 
homepage template. 
Then check

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I have a file on my theme called sidebar.php. I couldn't figure out why, but this file was being pulled into single-product.php in woocommerce/templates/. Once I realized that, I just wrote a quick script to tell sidebar.php to only display on the homepage and appear hidden on any other page. Thank you everyone for your help!